# Increase Selection.Resize everytime a condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a file where I and a few colleagues can share 'todo's' and comment on these. Now for deleting these comments I made a 'Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick' event. When double clicked, I try a macro to select all the comments do delete them using the Selection.Resize method. I came up with a code like this but it doesn't work:

```
Dim R_Selection As Range

If ActiveCell.Value = "R" Then
    'Resize to the size of one comment
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Resize(numRows + 2, numColumns + 2).Select
End If
Set R_Selection = Selection
'Go back to the cell where "R" is found
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate

NextReaction:
'Top of each comment is always 4 rows down
If ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Value = "R" Then
    
    'Resize to the size of two comments and increase the resize for each found comment
    R_Selection.Resize(numRows + 6, numColumns + 2).Select
    Set R_Selection = Selection
    
    'Go to the next cell where "R" can be found
    ActiveCell.Offset(4, 1).Activate
    
    'Repeat these steps over
    GoTo NextReaction

'If there's no more  "R" to be found, continue to clear the selected range
Else: GoTo ClearRange
End If
```

I need to, everytime the value "R" has been found, increase the selection by 6 rows and 2 columns and then find the next "R" to increase again, and so on until there's no more "R" to find.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction to accomplish this?
Thank you very much. Let me know if there's more information needed, or the question needs to be edited.

Comment: Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66823926/edit) to include sample data and the expected result.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really following your logic too well but something like this might be more appropriate here:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim c As Range, numRows As Long, numCols As Long, rng As Range
    
    Set c = Target.Offset(-1, 0) 'you can use Target (the double-clicked cell)
    Do While c.Value = "R"       'check for R
        numRows = numRows + 6
        numCols = numCols + 2
        Set c = c.Offset(4, 1)   'next cell to check
    Loop
    
    If numRows > 0 Then 'got any R values?
        Set rng = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(numRows, numCols)
        'do something to rng
    End If
End Sub
```

No need for `Select` / `Activate`

Comment: Tim, thank you, I user a do while loop to solve it to my needs, also used variables the way you recommended. I got it working.